# Can I add a friends Facebook account as one of my test users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook SDK, through my site, by fetching pictures. Right now I can only use my account (which is where my application is registered) to fetch and look at pictures. I tried entering one of my friends username/password and I received a error message, from Facebook, saying "your app is still in development mode, try adding a test user, etc, etc". So I then go into the developer portal page and create a new test user but it will be an empty user! Fine, but I want to test with my friend's login so that I can fetch all their pictures and not fetch an empty profile. Is this possible with the Facebook SDK?

Comment: Add your friend as a tester. You are also not allowed to use his login. You are only allowed to have one account and you are not allowed to share passwords

Comment: Log in to Facebook as the test user (can be done from app dashboard), and then upload some photos as that test user. Voila, you have what you need to work with, without getting friends involved in that very insecure way ...